# Why it gives an error can't be able to read property style

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [0] to get out from list, but it gives me:

> Error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I want to change the HTML element.

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
var width = window.innerWidth;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
document.body.style.height = height + "px";
document.body.style.width = width + "px";
x.style.height = height + "px";
x.style.width = width + "px";
```

Comment: WHat do you want to do exactly?

Comment: if you want to change the body and html size you dont need javascript for that, use css instead.

Comment: I Want to change the html, body Height and Width as a Inner Width , and Inner Height

Comment: What error you get? I run your code and it works without errors...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: An example: https://jsfiddle.net/rbf16tnx/1/

Answer (score 0):

It should suffice to use:

```
document.body.style
```

You don't need to additionally style the `<html>` element.

Comment: Plz Wite Full Code For Better Understnading Please

Comment: You're already using `document.body.style` correctly in the code you have provided in your question, @PuneetMakerobos.

Comment: I Want To know What is the Problem With x

Comment: Why Its Not Working as Expected , I Want To Provide Style To html Also